# Redux-saga - how to cancel forked process on action dispatch

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I have a following Saga:

```
function* interiorFileSaga() {
  yield [
    takeLatest(wizardActionTypes.UPLOAD_INTERIOR_FILE, handleInteriorFileUpload),
    takeLatest(wizardActionTypes.INTERIOR_FILE_PROCESSING, handleInteriorFileProcessing),
  ]
}
```

that is responsible for uploading and processing file. Inside the handleInteriorFileProcessing I'm having a while loop, that is checking file processing progress etc. I want to cancel the forked process, when we dispatch a certain action - when user changes page, on component unmount I want to stop the process. I know that cancel effect is taking a process as an argument. Is there a way I can cancel all child processes? What would be the correct syntax here, to cancel handleInteriorFileProcessing process on let's say CANCEL_BACKGROUND_JOB. I'm a Saga beginner and can't find a way to cancel a process in saga that is responsible for forking a few tasks like here.
Best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest would probably be to do

```
takeLatest([wizardActionTypes.INTERIOR_FILE_PROCESSING, CANCEL_BACKGROUND_JOB], handleInteriorFileProcessing)
```

and the check inside your function what actually happened.
This works because `takeLatest` cancels running tasks from that statement.

An alternative way to cancel things is to use the `race` effect, which cancels all 'losers'.